# How to Display jUnit Errors Via Ant

Tags: ant, junit

I am trying to add an Ant script to my company's project to run the jUnit tests. Here is what I have:

```
<target name="unit-tests">
    <junit>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${project.libext.dir}/junit-4.1.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${project.src-test.dir}/my/company/." />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

The script is grabbing my jUnit tests correctly, but it's saying there are errors. But all the output will say is things like:

```
[junit] Test package.MyTest FAILED
```

I want to know why it failed. I have tried adding a bunch of the attributes to the `junit` tag (`printsummary`, `showoutput`, etc), but can't seem to find the right combination. The best I have managed to get is:

```
[junit] Running package.MyTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
```

I really need the  full stack trace, etc as the test runs fine when I Run As > Junit Test via Eclipse.

Anyone know how to make the stack trace print?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer. Needed to add a formatter.

```
<target name="unit-tests">
    <junit>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${project.libext.dir}/junit-4.1.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${project.src-test.dir}/my/company/." />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the full stack trace from the tests in the Ant output AFAIK; it's embedded in the JUnit report file.  You can either browse that separately, or if you're using a continuous integration server such as Jenkins or CruiseControl to run your builds, you can set up a plugin that will link to the test reports.

Comment: How do you determine where the jUnit report file is located?

Comment: I am guessing the `todir` attribute on the `batchtest` tag, but that doesn't seem to be creating anything.